# Can a 9.6V Ni-MH battery be charged by unregulated 9V adaptor with 13.5V output?

Tags: charger, nimh

I am analyzing this Ni-MH charger circuit:

[image]

The charger is an unregulated power supply with 9 volts DC output.

[image]

The original battery is unknown but it is Ni-CD and someone told me he used Ni-MH 9.6volts 1500mAh rechargeable battery replacement for it but threw away the original battery so I couldn't see the voltage written on it. I don't have the battery yet.

Can an unregulated 9VDC output really charge a Ni-MH 9.6 volts rechargeable battery? The rule says the charger must always have higher voltage than the battery, but without load, the voltage of the unregulated 9V adapter is 13.8V. After it passes through the resistor and diode in the picture, it drops to 13.53V.  When I put a 1kohm resister in place of the battery, the voltage before the diode is 13.15V and after the diode is 11.42V.

I wonder if the battery is really 9.6volts Ni-MH. I need to know. Have you heard about 9 volts unregulated power supply charging a 9.6V Ni-MH battery (composed of eight 1.2V Ni-MH cells.) Can it charge?

If I buy a 9.6V Ni-MH 3000mAh, would draw the same power from the 9V adaptor as a 9.6V Ni-MH 1500mAh?

Comment: 9.6/1.2 = 8 cells. 13.5/8 = 1.7V/ cell.more than enough. At about C)10 rate you need about 1.45V X 8 = 11.6 V. As v rises above that I will drop.

Comment: If the batteries are completely empty.. can the unregulated 9V adaptor which acts like trickle charger able to completely charge it in time, or never reached full charge? If it can reach full charge..and the circuit can accept 1.4x8 = 11.2V, then ill just buy 8 Enveloop batteries for my Panasonic BQ-CC56 charger and use the charged batteries on the circuit.

Comment: The 9v charger will fully charge 8 NiMH if terminal voltage is at or above 11.2v BUT this may not be good for their lifetime depending on actual Vmax and final current. If you can use a properly designed charger utbis a much better idea. Eneloops are extremely good batteries.

Comment: Ill try to use usb 5v powerbank with 5 to 9 volts converter directly on the circuit without using any batteries..it should work in your experience, isnt it?

Comment: Should work if supply has adequate current handling capability. | For interest - are you South African.?

Comment: No. Im not South African. Say i still cant understand what Transistor in Answer below is saying when he wrote: "You know the voltage. You decide the current. You calculate the required resistance." What is the resistance of a Nicd or NiMH battery? And how do you decide the current? what is he talking about?

Answer (score 2):

If I've correctly read the resistor colour-code as brown, black, black, black then it appears to be a 100 Ω current-limiting resistor.

This would limit the current to \$ \frac {13.5 - 9.6}{100} = 39 \ \text {mA}\$.

In general you can safely charge NiCd batteries indefinitely at C/16. For a 1500 mAh battery this would be a charge of a little less than 100 mA so < 40 mA should be OK. NiMH batteries do not seem to be so tolerant. [Electronics Notes](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/battery-technology/nimh-nickel-metal-hydride-charging.php) says this:

> NiMH trickle charging
> As NiMH batteries are intolerant to overcharge, trickle charging tem has to be undertaken with care.

> While NiCd batteries may be trickle charged at a rate of around 0.1C, this is considered too high for NiMH batteries and it is generally accepted that for most NiMH batteries trickle charging should be accomplished at a rate of about 0.05C.

> Even when trickle charging at this rate, it is advisable not to leave them trickle charging for too long. It is better not to trickle charge and to replenish any self-discharge before use.

> Often cells within items like cordless phones and many other items that are "always on" will trickle charge the cells within them that are often NiMH cells over long periods of time. While some may have elementary forms of battery management within them, many also do not.

> Therefore it is necessary to be prepared to replace the cells periodically.

If you need to charge in this way then you might consider adding another 100 Ω in series for safety.

Comment: But can the 9V unregulated adaptor really charge even 9.6V Ni-Cd batteries? note the charger has less voltage than the battery.

Comment: You've stated that the measured output voltage is considerably above 9 V. The rating on an unregulated supply usually means that it will give at least 9 V on full load at minimum mains supply voltage.

Comment: It is considerably above 9V without any batteries . But if I buy and put the 9.6V batteries. I dont know if it will become 9V only. What do you think?

Comment: Test it. Load it up with enough resistors to draw the required current and measure the voltage.

Comment: How do I know what is the equivalent resistance of 9.6V Ni-MH or 9.6V Ni-Cd?

Comment: You know the voltage. You decide the current. You calculate the required resistance.

Comment: I know the voltage as 9.6V or 13.5V? What is the required current? You meant 100mA?  pls add to your answer above what is the internal resistance of a 9.6V Ni-MH because im still confused with your descriptions in the comments. I want to know if the 9V adaptor can really charge either 9.6V rechargeble. pls address this in your edited answer. Many thanks.